# Unmet dependency: xscrnsaver

Tags: c++, qt, chromium

when I build qtwebengine with following this [steps](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Try_QtWebEngine#Building_QtWebengine), I get

```
Unmet dependency: xscrnsaver
QtWebEngine will not be built.
```

I cannot find xscrnsaver with `sudo apt-file find xscrnsaver`, and even I `sudo apt-get install xscreensaver`, the error still exist, how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

I find the solution, the reason is I miss `libxss` since I copy(from guide) following code to terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libxcursor-dev libxcomposite-dev libxdamage-dev libxrandr-dev
libfontconfig1-dev libxss-dev
```

code has 2 lines, it means I doesn't install "libfontconfig1-dev libxss-dev", so the right code is:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libxcursor-dev libxcomposite-dev libxdamage-dev libxrandr-dev libfontconfig1-dev libxss-dev
```